# Running a "this" Method inside actionPerformed - JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a JButton which I added a actionPerformed, and I tried to write a "this" method and it won't allow it. How can I do this? This is example of what I want to do:

```
public void methodName(String results) {
    this.results = results;
}

Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    this.methodName(asdf);                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's an anonymous class, using `this` will refer to the anonymous class instance, not your overall class. To get around this, denote that you want to reference your outer class specifically:

```
Something some = new Something() {

    public void overridden() {
        YourClass.this.methodName("test");
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class in anonymous, so in anonymous context, `this` does not make any sense. What do you mean by `this`? If you mean the button, your answer is `event.getSource()`

Comment: I want to call a method from the class i currently am in, not button.

Comment: @user3060035 Than I am voting up Rogue's answer.

Comment: Thanks Engin Kayraklioglu!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `this` refers to your `ActionListener` when you call the method.

If you want to call `methodName()` from the enclosing class, you have two choices :

- remove `this`:

  ```
  Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          methodName(asdf);                                                 
  }
  ```
- store a reference to the enclosing class and use it:

  ```
  final MyClass enclosingClass = this;
  Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
          enclosingClass.methodName(asdf);                                                 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use "this" keyword inside inner class to access outer class method. if we use this then it will refer to the inner class.Instead of that just use the method name.see the example.

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;


    public class TestButton
    {
      String results = "";
      JButton Button = new JButton();

      public TestButton(){
        Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
               methodName("Test");  
               this.show();
          }

          public void show(){
            System.out.println("hi");
          }
        });
      }

      public void methodName(String results) 
      {
        this.results = results;
      }


    }
```